# EIGRP active timer

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, eigrp

Barring things like `sh run | s eigrp` - are there any show commands which will display the configured active timer value for a given eigrp process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EIGRP active timer is displayed using the `show ip protocols` command.

```
R1#show ip protocols | i eigrp|Active    
Routing Protocol is "eigrp 123"
  Active Timer: 3 min
```

Answer (score 2):

`show eigrp address-family timers`

That should display the information that you are looking for.

I think.  I don't typically fiddle with the timers.